# Prove the following are independent

Tags: self-study, independence

I have been unable to figure out the following question

$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=N(x,x^2)$

$f_X(x)=U(0,1)$

Prove that $\frac{Y}{X}$ and $X$ are independent

Comment: What does $Y|X$ mean? There is a _conditional_ distribution of $Y$ given the value of $X$ that uses notation like $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ but $Y|X$ is not a random variable.

Comment: I am sorry that was supposed to mean $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$

Comment: I think the OP probably means "Prove that $Y/X$ and $X$ are independent" rather than "Prove that $Y|X$ and $X$ are independent."

Comment: @Flounderer was right. The question was about proving $\frac{Y}{X}$ and $X$ are independent which was straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had misunderstood the question originally. I have edited the question now and here is a brief answer since I have already put up the question.

I used the following transformations

$U =\frac{Y}{X}$

$V = X$

Then use the standard bivariate transformation short cut for one-to-one functions